# How to fix list error not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my script I want to use this proxy list: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarketm/proxy-list/master/proxy-list.txt

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 43, in <module>
    proxies = list(set([f'{ip}:{port}' for ip, port in proxies]))
  File "script.py", line 43, in <listcomp>
    proxies = list(set([f'{ip}:{port}' for ip, port in proxies]))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is the section in the script:

```
def download():
    raw_text = requests.get(proxy_url).text
    lines = raw_text.split('\n')
    # lines = [l.strip() for l in lines if l.strip().endswith('+')]
    lines = [l.strip() for l in lines[4:] if '-S' in l]
    proxies = [l.split(' ')[0].split(':') for l in lines]
    return proxies


if os.path.exists(proxy_file) and os.path.isfile(proxy_file):
    with open('proxies.txt', 'r') as f:
        proxies = f.readlines()
    proxies = list(set([proxy.strip() for proxy in proxies]))
else:
    proxies = download()
    proxies = list(set([f'{ip}:{port}' for ip, port in proxies]))
```

I am on Python 3.6 - thank you for your help!

Comment: Something doesn't contain a `:`, which means `proxies` contains at least one 1-tuple consisting of only an IP address, without a port,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
This includes the entire error message, with traceback, and your execution trace -- critical values just before the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `proxies = download()` the first entry (`proxies[0]`) is `['IP']`, probably the header.

just skip it.

replace the last line with:
 `proxies = list(set([f'{ip}:{port}' for ip, port in proxies[1:]]))`

(or better yet, fix `download` to skip it)

Comment: works! thank you! I fixed the starting line in download as suggested.